# Python time series data bases

Tags: python

I will have hourly temperature data for each city in US which needs some kind of statistical and plotting post-processing using grandfathered tools in Python. Right now the list has only few cities but it will grown to include more cities.

Each city with hourly temperature data is thus a 2 column vector. The first column being hourly date-time and the second column as temperature.

What is the suggested open source database tool that I can use as I am trying to avoid keeping this temperature data in csv file.

Edit: I also get 10 day hourly temperature forecast each day for each city. I want to store the city historical forecast I receive from vendor every day also.

Comment: Since your data is very simple, you can certainly use something like MySql. But, any noSql database like MongoDB should also be fine. It really depends on operations you want to perform with your data.

Comment: If you want to do some numerical stuff with this and only care about speed, using `numpy.ndarrays` and storing them in binary format (`numpy.save`) is a good way. You might also look at `pandas`, it's often used to analyse finance time series: http://quant-econ.net/py/pandas.html

Comment: `pandas` has an array-like sturcture called `DataFrame` which is very easy to manipulate. Have a look at it here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html